# How to render jquery objects to html - seeing [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue getting jquery objects to render as html.

In the code below, the `tickBox` gets rendered as `[object Object]` and not as html whereas all the rest is rendered correctly.

I know I could just add it as a string but that's not the goal here.

**Why does the `tickBox` not render as html?**

```js
const legendData = ['hello world', 'welcome back', 'hotel california', 'never leave'];

const tickBox = $('<div/>', {
  class: 'tickBox',
  html: $('<div/>', {
    class: 'ticked'
  })
});

const legendContent = legendData.map(item => {
  return $('<li/>', {
    dataId: `${item.split(' ')[0]}`,
    html: `${tickBox} ${item}`
    /* I know I could do this */
    //html: `<div class="tickBox"><div class="ticked"></div></div> ${item}`
  });
});

$('<div/>', {
  id: 'chartLegend',
  class: 'legend',
  title: 'Chart legend',
  html: '<p id="chartLegendHeader">Legend</p>'
}).appendTo(`#chartContainer`);

$('<ul/>', {
  class: 'legend',
  html: legendContent
}).appendTo('#chartLegend');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

Comment: @RakeshSojitra Why should he? He's already added a snippet.

Comment: I assume it's because you're trying to output a jQuery object not using jQuery for the task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you somehow need to serialize the HTML node to string, so that the interpolation works correctly.

One way is to use `outerHTML` of the corresponding native element:

```js
const legendData = ['hello world', 'welcome back', 'hotel california', 'never leave'];

const tickBox = $('<div/>', {
  class: 'tickBox',
  html: $('<div/>', {
    class: 'ticked'
  })
});

const legendContent = legendData.map(item => {
  return $('<li/>', {
    dataId: `${item.split(' ')[0]}`,
    html: `${tickBox[0].outerHTML} ${item}`
  });
});

$('<div/>', {
  id: 'chartLegend',
  class: 'legend',
  title: 'Chart legend',
  html: '<p id="chartLegendHeader">Legend</p>'
}).appendTo(`#chartContainer`);

$('<ul/>', {
  class: 'legend',
  html: legendContent
}).appendTo('#chartLegend');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I actually went with `const tickBox = $('<div/>', {
  class: 'tickBox',
  html: $('<div/>', {
    class: 'ticked'
  })
})[0].outerHTML;` which keeps the code a bit cleaner to me, so thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

The documentation states that the `jQuery()` function takes an argument of `PlainObject`. `PlainObject` takes a `html` parameter that it expects to be a string already. It is presently stringifying a Javascript object into a string, hence `[object Object]`.

You should render this into a HTML string.

Comment: Actually this is the only real **answer** to OP's question *Why does the tickBox not render as html?* Unfortunately it does not offer a solution which can be applied as-is.

Comment: I often find wisdom exists between answers as well as within them. Multiple answers are just as desirable as one cohesive solution :)

Answer (score 1):

use tickBox[0].innerHTML to render the html content inside tickBox

```js
const legendData = ['hello world', 'welcome back', 'hotel california', 'never leave'];

const tickBox = $('<div/>', {
  class: 'tickBox',
  html: $('<div/>', {
    class: 'ticked'
  })
});

const legendContent = legendData.map(item => {
  return $('<li/>', {
    dataId: `${item.split(' ')[0]}`,
    html: `${tickBox[0].innerHTML} ${item}`
    /* I know I could do this */
    //html: `<div class="tickBox"><div class="ticked"></div></div> ${item}`
  });
});
$('<div/>', {
  id: 'chartLegend',
  class: 'legend',
  title: 'Chart legend',
  html: '<p id="chartLegendHeader">Legend</p>'
}).appendTo(`#chartContainer`);

$('<ul/>', {
  class: 'legend',
  html: legendContent
}).appendTo('#chartLegend');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Check the source when rendered, you'll see this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you have to take HTML instead of an object like. you are using the whole object into HTML option. you just need to change a line

```
`${tickBox} ${item}`
```

to

```
`${tickBox.wrapAll('<div>').parent().html()} ${item}`
```

Or to

```
`${tickBox[0].outerHTML} ${item}`
```

For

```
const legendContent = legendData.map(item => {
  return $('<li/>', {
    dataId: `${item.split(' ')[0]}`,
    html: `${tickBox.wrapAll('<div>').parent().html()} ${item}`
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp61jnua/4/)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: It's working sir... I have added jsfiddle you can check it

Comment: No, it's not, check the source. `tickBox` is two divs, your solution removes the outer `<div>`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: alright I got your point and I have corrected my answer you can verify it.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: OP is same as the accepted answer. `<li dataid="hello"><div class="tickBox"><div class="ticked"></div></div> hello world</li>`. Did you checked updated jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to concatenating the HTML of the `tickBox` element would be to `clone()` a new instance of it and `append()` that to each `legendContent` entity, like this:

```
const legendContent = legendData.map(item => {
  return $('<li/>', {
    dataId: `${item.split(' ')[0]}`,
  }).append(tickBox.clone()).append(item);
});
```

```js
const legendData = ['hello world', 'welcome back', 'hotel california', 'never leave'];

const tickBox = $('<div/>', {
  class: 'tickBox',
  html: $('<div/>', {
    class: 'ticked'
  })
});

const legendContent = legendData.map(item => {
  return $('<li/>', {
    dataId: `${item.split(' ')[0]}`,
  }).append(tickBox.clone()).append(item);
});

$('<div/>', {
  id: 'chartLegend',
  class: 'legend',
  title: 'Chart legend',
  html: '<p id="chartLegendHeader">Legend</p>'
}).appendTo(`#chartContainer`);

$('<ul/>', {
  class: 'legend',
  html: legendContent
}).appendTo('#chartLegend');
```

```css
.tickBox {
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```