# why do I see [object object] in my html instead of the content of the table?

Tags: javascript, html

In my JS code I'm using the following method for displaying a table on my webpage:

```
function display(data) {
    var photoUrls = data.photoUrls;
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    for(var i=0;i<photoUrls.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("single row: "+photoUrls[i]);
        var row = "<tr><td>"+photoUrls[i]+"</td></tr>";
        $("#mytable").append(row);
    }
    var outcome = "<h4>Photo URLs:</h4>";

    $('#feedback').html(outcome+tbl);
}
```

and instead of seeing the table, all I see is:

```
Photo URLs:
[object Object]
```

That is weird because the console log shows me appropriate names in the console, so I expected it to display table properly. What's wrong with my code then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render jquery objects to html - seeing \[object Object\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811308/how-to-render-jquery-objects-to-html-seeing-object-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `console.log`, you're concatenating strings. In your last line, you're trying to use `+` between a string and an object. This causes the object to be converted to a string via `.toString()`. Objects usually stringify to "[object Object]".

The simplest fix (though not necessarily the best) is to use this instead:

```
function display(data) {
    var photoUrls = data.photoUrls;
    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    for(var i=0;i<photoUrls.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("single row: "+photoUrls[i]);
        var row = "<tr><td>"+photoUrls[i]+"</td></tr>";
        tbl.append(row); /* fix 1 */
    }
    var outcome = "<h4>Photo URLs:</h4>";

    $('#feedback').append(outcome).append(tbl); /* fix 2 */
}
```

1. `#mytable` doesn't exist in the document thus `$('#mytable')` produces an empty jQuery collection so the trailing `.append()` doesn't achieve anything. (jQuery doesn't usually fail when an operation is performed on an empty collection so this can catch new developers off guard.)
2. Rather than trying to concatenate strings, just append them to the target directly. (jQuery does some magic so it can usually accept strings, elements, or jQuery collections.)

Comment: thank you very much, so what do you think is the best fix in this case?

Comment: @randomuser1 A rewrite taking into account principles and techniques you don't have a grasp on just yet. It looks like you're heading in the right direction, you just need to get more experience, through both training courses and practice while critically reexamining your older code and thinking about how you can improve your new code.

Comment: Thanks, thouse are tough words, but unfortunately they're real. I'm just starting with JS. Anyway, when I pasted your code `$('#feedback').html(outcome+tbl.html());` - now there's only displayed the sentence `Photo URLs:`, and the table is missing (the same for `[object Object]` - it does not show up at all right now.

Comment: @randomuser1 Apologies, that's what I get for trying to do it off the top of my head. I've updated my answer to a tested solution.

Comment: thank you very much, I appreciate not only a solution, but also an explanation. All the best!